# How to make Grunt search a specific directory for node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, filepath

Grunt looks in the same folder for node_modules, but how can I tell it to look in a different folder path? I want it to look in "./js/vendor" for its modules

Comment: I have a Gruntfile.js file. I use "grunt watch" to run it. Inside are tasks that watch my less files for changes and outputs a minified css file. Grunt looks inside the "node_modules" folder in the same directory for its modules, but I instead want it to look inside "js/vendor/" for its modules.

Comment: Looks like it's not something supported by default, but you may be able to do by CWD'ing to the directory you want to search. Have a look at issue #696 on Grunt's GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work as described in the issue [#696](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/696) on Grunt's GitHub issue tracker.

```
// if you want to overload the directory on the CLI
grunt --dir=<your dir to search>

// example CLI command (relative to Gruntfile)
grunt --dir=${PWD}/js/vendor2

/**
 * Add the following code to your
 * Gruntfile.
 */

// set the custom or default directory
var customDir = grunt.option('dir') || process.cwd() + '/js/vendor';

// get the current working directory
var cwd = process.cwd();

// switch to custom directory (contains node_modules folder)
process.chdir(customDir);

// load taks(s)
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify2');

// switch back to original directory
process.chdir(cwd);
```